# Why didn't Odo arrest Kira?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the episode [Necessary Evil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Necessary_Evil_(episode)) Odo has arrested Mrs. Vaatrik on charges of blackmail, and believes she murdered her husband.

In the end Odo realizes that Kira murdered the husband after the husband caught her searching for a list.

Why didn't Odo arrest Kira or tell Sisko? He would have added a murder charge to Mrs. Vaatrik record, but he had to prove it first.

Comment: I doubt that a Bajoran resistance fighter killing a collaborator is considered a crime under Bajoran law.

Comment: Also, he had a crash on her, so I guess he was not impartial...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kira's history as a member of the Bajoran Resistance is well known and public knowledge. Given that she undertook various actions that killed Bajorans working for the Cardassians (as well as Cardassians), it would appear that a general amnesty was offered to Resistance members after the occupation ended. The killing of a collaborator would simply be regarded as a legitimate target.

> **KIRA:** *She wasn't, at least not officially. Fala spent the occupation cleaning floors in a Cardassian records office in Dahkur Province. She passed us information for years without anyone catching on. But she was always so afraid. Afraid that she'd be caught and executed. But she never stopped. I once told her that I thought she was braver than all of us, because she had to live with her fear every day. Even after the occupation was over, she didn't want anyone to know that she was secretly helping us. She was worried that someone would come looking for her for revenge.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Darkness and the Light](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/509.htm)</sup></sub>